# Is this PDE boundary value problem well posed?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

I have this problem from my class of hamiltonian mechanics:

> Given the Klein-Gordon equation $u_{tt}=c^2u_{xx}-\omega^2u$ with boundary conditions $u(t,0)=u(t,l)=0$, $u_t(t,0)=u_t(t,l)=0, \forall t\geq0$. Find a solution by separation of variables $u(t,x)=f(t)g(x)$.

Using separation of variables I found $$g_k(x)=b_k \sin(\mu_k x),$$ $$f_k(t)=\alpha_k \cos((\mu_k^2 c^2+\omega^2)t)+\beta_k \sin((\mu_k^2 c^2+\omega^2)t),$$ where $b_k,\alpha_k,\beta_k$ are constants to be found using the conditions and $\mu_k=\frac{2k\pi}{l}$, for $k\geq1$ natural. At this point, ususally, I proceed like this: I define $U_k(t,x)=g_k(x)f_k(x)$ and then I consider the infinite superposition of $U_k$ and use the conditions to find the coefficients.
**The problems are:**

- I don't think it makes much sense to consider a superposition of $U_k$ since
  there is no initial condition to impose and the conditions on $u_t$ are satisfied by any $U_k$.
- The conditions on $u_t$ doesn't really add any useful information to find the coefficients, since $U_k$ satisfies it for every choice of the coefficients.
- Even assuming that $U_k$ is the solution for some $k$, it seems strange that it depends on 3 arbitrary parameters.

My questions are: Am I missing something? Is the problem well posed (i.e. existence and uniqueness of the solution) with this boundary conditions?

Comment: There is not enough information here. You need to know, for example, $u(0,x)$ and $u_t(0,x)$ to uniquely determine the solution. Also note that there are not three but two independent constants, as $b_k$ can be absorbed into $\alpha_k$ and $\beta_k$.

Comment: I suspected it but I wanted an external opinion since my professor had not yet answered to my mail. I didn't know that $b_k$ can be absorbed into the other two parameters. Well, thanks

Comment: What you can do is to write down the solution as function of general initial conditions:
$$u(x,t) = \sum_{k\geq 1} [a_k\cos(\omega_k t) + b_k\sin(\omega_k t)] \sin(\mu_k x)$$
where $\omega_k = \sqrt{\omega^2+\mu_k^2}$ and $\int_0^\ell u(0,x)\sin(\mu_k x){\rm d}x = \int_0^\ell a_k\sin^2(\mu_k x){\rm d}x$ and we can make a similar expression for $b_k$ in terms of $u_t(0,x)$.

Comment: You are right, I didn't think about it! If you write it as an answer I can accept it (just not to leave the question unanswered)